# Filter keys of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have these hashes in `hashes` variable:

```
{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"JPY", :name=>"Japanese Yen", :symbol=>"¥", :alternate_symbols=>["円", "圓"], :subunit=>"Sen", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"&#x00A5;", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>""}
{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZWD", :name=>"Zimbabwean Dollar", :symbol=>"$", :alternate_symbols=>["Z$"], :subunit=>"Cent", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"$", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"716"}
{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZWL", :name=>"Zimbabwean Dollar", :symbol=>"$", :alternate_symbols=>["Z$"], :subunit=>"Cent", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"$", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"932"}
{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZWN", :name=>"Zimbabwean Dollar", :symbol=>"$", :alternate_symbols=>["Z$"], :subunit=>"Cent", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"$", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"942"}
{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"ZWR", :name=>"Zimbabwean Dollar", :symbol=>"$", :alternate_symbols=>["Z$"], :subunit=>"Cent", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"$", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>"935"}
```

I want to fill/update `hashes` variable with only three keys:

```
:iso_code
:name
:symbol
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"JPY", :name=>"Japanese Yen", :symbol=>"¥", :alternate_symbols=>["円", "圓"], :subunit=>"Sen", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"&#x00A5;", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>""}
.select{|k, _| [:iso_code, :name, :symbol].include?(k)}
# => {:iso_code=>"JPY", :name=>"Japanese Yen", :symbol=>"¥"}
```

Comment: can you please explain |k, _|....what the underscore means ?

Comment: @sunny1304 The block in this case takes two variables: the key and the value for each pair in the hash. The underscore is a convention in Ruby to indicate a variable that is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [keep_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if) hash method

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > hsh = {:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"JPY", :name=>"Japanese Yen", :symbol=>"¥", :alternate_symbols=>["円", "圓"], :subunit=>"Sen", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"&#x00A5;", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>""}
 => {:priority=>100, :iso_code=>"JPY", :name=>"Japanese Yen", :symbol=>"¥", :alternate_symbols=>["円", "圓"], :subunit=>"Sen", :subunit_to_unit=>100, :symbol_first=>true, :html_entity=>"&#x00A5;", :decimal_mark=>".", :thousands_separator=>",", :iso_numeric=>""} 
1.9.3p392 :002 > hsh.keep_if {|key,value| ([:iso_code, :name, :symbol]).include?(key)}
 => {:iso_code=>"JPY", :name=>"Japanese Yen", :symbol=>"¥"}
```